# Can not use gradle as non-admin users in linux

Tags: linux, gradle

For example command "gradle tasks --info" returns FAILURE with line Couldn't create lock file for /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4/bin/daemon/7.4/registry.bin.lock
Same command as superuser works fine.
I've tried to give all users permissions for /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4/bin/daemon, but they can only run gradle command once. Then permissions become drwx------ again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user should have their own personal folder that holds the daemons/cache/etc. It would appear that something on that system is setting a value to `GRADLE_USER_HOME` that is not the default:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties

> GRADLE_USER_HOME
>
> Specifies the Gradle user home directory (which
> defaults to /.gradle if not set).

You could possibly either find the place that is setting the incorrect value for this, or you can globally set the value of `GRADLE_USER_HOME` for all users to `$HOME/.gradle`.